# Authservice vs AngularFirestore

Tags: php, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am using `AuthService` to call my MySql database with PHP api and therefore my PHP functions for my Ionic 3 Angular 4 app.

This is how I call to get `userData` and it works fine

```
import { AuthService } from "../../providers/auth-service";

...

constructor(
  public authService: AuthService,
  private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
) {
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  this.userDetails = data.userData;
  this.userPostData.uid = this.userDetails.uid;
  let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });
}
```

I have another project that uses `AngularFirestore`

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from  'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

and calls the `constructor` like this

```
private users: AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>;

constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  private afService: AngularFirestore,
  private storage: Storage,
  private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
) {
  this.uid = localStorage.getItem('uid');
  this.users = this.afService.collection('users').doc(this.uid);
  let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });
  loader.present();
  this.users.valueChanges()
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.canDoMessage = res.canDoMessage;
      loader.dismiss();
    }, error => {
      loader.dismiss();
    });
}
```

I just want to understand what calling `this.afService.collection` does?

Basically what i am asking is how to call the 'users' on AuthService

```
  constructor( public authService: AuthService,,
```

like this on Firestone

```
  constructor(private afService: AngularFirestore) { **this.users = afService.collection('users')**; }
```

Comment: Maybe it's the English. But it's not really very clear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: No its not the english. I am new at ionic and Angular. What do 'users' call? The table users form the Firestone database?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *What do 'users' call?*

Comment: Why it is there for? Why the developer calls it, what does it do? Calls the table?

Comment: *this.users = this.afService.collection('users').doc(this.uid);* retrieves the document *this.uid* from the *users* collection as shown in the [FireStore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).  *users* is a var (variable) and doesn't perform any calls, it simply holds data. Is there more to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting `AngularFirestore` as a dependency and you will have an instance of it in `afService`.

When you call `this.afService.collection('users')` it returns to you an **[`AngularFirestoreCollection<{}>`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#3-collections-in-angularfirestore)** which is a wrapper around the native Firestore SDK's `CollectionReference` and `Query` types. It is a generic service that provides you with a strongly typed set of methods like `valueChanges()`, `snapshotChanges()`, `stateChanges()`, and `auditTrail()` for streaming data.

When you call `this.afService.collection('users').doc(this.uid)`, it returns to you an **[`AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#2-documents-in-angularfirestore)** which is a wrapper around the native Firestore SDK's `DocumentReference` type. It is a generic service that provides you with a strongly typed set of methods like `valueChanges()` and `snapshotChanges()` for streaming data.

Since Firebase is event based, these APIs that you have on `AngularFirestoreCollection` and `AngularFirestoreDocument` gives you a way to stream data in a form that you're familiar with(using `Observable`s in Angular)

Please follow the links to go through the docs to read more about these types.

Comment: Thanks for you time Sidd i just dont know how to call the users using Authservice not Firestone

Comment: Please create a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) properly stating your issue.

Comment: OK i did a sample with the auth-service file in providers folder, a login page and a search page at pages folder to show how my authservice works: stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcawuu . And this is how firestone works on search page: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mu9rm1  What  i want to know is how to use my authService on search files with firestone. On the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mu9rm1 that is to implement not firestone but providers/authService/ I know its the same thing. But i want to know how to use local database

Comment: Basically what i am asking is how to call the 'users' on AuthService constructor(
        public authService: AuthService,, like this on Firestone  constructor(private afService: AngularFirestore) {
    this.users = afService.collection('users');
  }

Answer (score 0):

I just want to understand what calling this.afService.collection does?

Ans:-
The AngularFirestoreCollection service is a wrapper around the native Firestore SDK's CollectionReference and Query types. It is a generic service that provides you with a strongly typed set of methods for manipulating and streaming data. This service is designed for use as an @Injectable().

The AngularFirestoreCollection is a service you use to create streams of the collection and perform data operations on the underyling collection.

```
this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
```

Try This Code

```
this.users = this.afService.collection<user>('users').doc(this.uid);
```

Check Out The Link :- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md